# org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Unknown datum type

Tags: scala, enums, avro

I'm using avro version 1.7.7, scala version 2.11.8

My avro schema is called EntityAuth and the enum in it looks like this

```
            {
              "name": "reason",
              "type": [
                "null", 
                {
                  "type": "enum",
                  "name": "BlockedSiteReasonType",
                  "symbols": [
                    "REASON_1",
                    "REASON_2",
                    "REASON_3",
                    "REASON_4",
                    "ADMIN_SITE_CATEGORY_FILTER",
                    "REASON_6",
                    "REASON_7",
                    "REASON_8",
                    "REASON_9"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "doc": "Agent blocked the entity",
              "default": null
            }
```

My code to write an avro file looks like this. EntityAuth is the avro schema class

```
class EntitySerializationStream(codec: CodecFactory = CodecFactory.snappyCodec()) {
  private val schema = EntityAuth.getClassSchema
  private val datumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter[EntityAuth](schema)
  private val fileName = "some-file-name"
  private val tempFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, "avro.tmp")
  tempFile.deleteOnExit()

  private val dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter[EntityAuth](datumWriter)
  dataFileWriter.setCodec(codec)
  dataFileWriter.create(schema, tempFile)

  def append(e: EntityAuth) = {
    dataFileWriter.append(e)
  }
```

The exception I get when I try to append a record to the Generic data file writer is

```
org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Unknown datum type com.goguardian.events.auth.BlockedSiteReasonType: ADMIN_SITE_CATEGORY_FILTER
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:296)
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Unknown datum type com.goguardian.events.auth.BlockedSiteReasonType: ADMIN_SITE_CATEGORY_FILTER
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.getSchemaName(GenericData.java:636)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.resolveUnion(GenericData.java:601)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.resolveUnion(GenericDatumWriter.java:151)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:71)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeField(GenericDatumWriter.java:114)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:104)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:66)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeArray(GenericDatumWriter.java:138)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:68)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeField(GenericDatumWriter.java:114)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:104)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:66)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:58)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:290)
        ... 22 more
```

This is only happening when I'm writing an avro file. When I read the avro file I can parse it just fine.

Comment: Why the class name of the enum type in exception, is `BlockedSiteReasonType`, which is not the same as `ReasonType` in the schema json?

Comment: @tianzhipeng Good point. They are the same. Edited the schema.

Comment: Please show how `EntityAuth` is defined. Do you generate this with `avro4s`, or similar tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have generate Java Class using this schema. Please replace

```
private val schema = EntityAuth.getClassSchema
private val datumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter[EntityAuth](schema)
```

to

```
private val datumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter[EntityAuth](classOf[EntityAuth])
```

SpecificDatumWriter is for generated Java classes.
GenericDatumWriter is for generic Java objects, without code generation.